# lubridate conversion functions stopped working after R update

Tags: r, lubridate

Until today, I was using R 4.0.X, and used `lubridate` functions `dmy_hms`, `ymd_hms`, etc. to convert dates as strings into datetime objects in dataframes.
So, this MWE worked just fine:

```
library('lubridate');
a <- '13/06/2019 18:00';
dmy_hm(a);
```

After an update to R 4.2.2 (and an update of lubridate package), this does not works anymore, and yields, without more information:

```
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Function `parse_date_time` seems to work (see below), but I would need to update all of my scripts that are using `dmy_hm` (or other) functions.

```
> parse_date_time(a, "dmy HM")
 1 parsed with %d/%Om/%Y %H:%M
[1] "2019-06-13 18:00:00 UTC"
```

Does anyone knows how to make these functions work?
Thanks

---

Also, if this could help:

```
> Sys.getlocale (category = "LC_ALL")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252"

> version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.2                              
year           2022                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        83211                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

Comment: `dmy_hm()` works fine for me with R 4.2.2 and lubridate 1.9.0

Comment: Does temporarily setting another locale (e. g. `Sys.setlocale (category = "LC_TIME", "English_US")`) work?

Comment: @I_O Yes, setting locale to `English_US` works, so it’s an issue with locale… It’s strange it appears now.